# Lambda for summing shorthand

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following LINQ query:

```
var q = from bal in data.balanceDetails
        where bal.userName == userName && bal.AccountID == accountNumber
        select new
        {
            date = bal.month + "/" + bal.year,
            commission = bal.commission,
            rebate = bal.rebateBeforeService,
            income = bal.commission - bal.rebateBeforeService
        };
```

I remember seeing a lambda shorthand for summing the `commission` field for each row of `q`.
What would be the best way of summing this? Aside from manually looping through the results?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's easy - no need to loop within your code:

```
var totalCommission = q.Sum(result => result.commission);
```

Note that if you're going to use the results of `q` for various different calculations (which seems a reasonable assumption, as if you only wanted the total commission I doubt that you'd be selecting the other bits) you *may* want to materialize the query *once* so that it doesn't need to do all the filtering and projecting multiple times. One way of doing this would be to use:

```
var results = q.ToList();
```

That will create a `List<T>` for your anonymous type - you can still use the `Sum` code above on `results` here.